# Occasional Error Establishing a Database Connection

Tags: database

I have two small WooComm WP sites on Vultr and both of them work for a few days and then I get the old "Error Establishing a Database Connection" error. If I reboot the server they work again for a while before going offline again. I have seen others with this problem and people suggesting a password issue but I don't think that this is that case here otherwise they wouldn't work at all?

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a WordPress issue. More likely it is some server-related stuff. 
Is there a chance that the SQL server dies after a few days?
When you encounter this issue next time, try checking the status of MySQL server.

Comment: Are you running MySQL on the same instance as the website? Have you set the memory limit for the database? I'd guess you'll see out of memory or allocation errors in the mysql logs after a failure.

Comment: I can't answer either of these questions, I am totally non-technical. Happy to send a few beer tokens to anyone that can fix this for me?

Comment: If you used the Vultr one-click WordPress set up then they ought to have set that up for you, so I'd ask them for help.